# Does HAXM allocation affect android emulator speed?

Tags: android-studio, haxm

I am wondering if will my android studio emulator performance speed up if i increase HAXM RAM allocation? I have 24GB ram and I am thinking of increasing HAXM RAM allocation to like 10GB. Is there any advantages if I increase it to 10GB? Or shall I just use the recommended RAM allocation (2GB)?